# Script to check ntp status for two server NTP

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

We want to synchronize our server clock with an NTP time server.
Design a Script to send an NTP request to a time service (paris: ntp-p1.obspm.fr) and recover the response (script bach), If ever this ntp server does not respond timeoout or does not respond within a time limit outsourced (socket timeout) after 15 s for example, send the request to a second server (from besenson: ntp-p1.obspm.fr for example).
If he does not respond either, notify the administrator by email

Answer (score 1):

Ideally NTP is running as a deamon talking to multiple servers all day. That way it can leverage averaging and statistical methods to identify outliers and bad servers. If NTP is operating in this mode it already maintains detailed information about its peers. You can view this data by running

```
$ ntpq -c associations
ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 27930  962a   yes   yes  none  sys.peer    sys_peer  2
  2 27931  941d   yes   yes  none candidate              1
$ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*ntpserver       .GPS.            1 u  553 1024  377    0.169    0.300   0.223
+ntpserver2      10.41.200.62     2 u  193 1024  377    0.493    0.307   0.168
```

The first character in the last two lines is called "tally code" and might be of particular interest to you. If you see " " here the peer is not used - either because it is unreachable or because there is another serious problem that prevents it from being used. See the [man page of ntpq](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpq) for details. You could hook that into your monitoring like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
output=`ntpq -p | tail -n +3 | cut -d' ' -f1`

for line in $output; do
  tallycode=${line:0:1}
  host=${line:1}
  if [[ "$tallycode" == [#+\*] ]]; then
    echo "Info: Found good NTP peer $host"
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Warning: bad NTP peer $host"
  fi
done
echo "Error: None of the peers provides useful time!"
exit -1
```

If you rather want to perform a dumb single-shot test for each server you could parse the output of `sntp -t 15 <servername>` instead. But the approach above should be significantly more robust.

Comment: the echo "Warning: bad NTP peer $host" dosen't work and please how can i define the time out